# Continuous beeping on startup

Tags: 12.04, boot, startup, restart

I'm having a problem with my ubuntu 12.04 right after installation, I've restarted it several times and it went just fine. After that I'm getting these continuous beeps right after post that I haven't experience in my previous OS.

Sometimes it doesn't come, sometimes it does. When I boot or restart with a bootable flash drive connected, the beeping doesn't occur but when I start my laptop alone without any bootable flash connected, the beeping goes on.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: this is generally related to RAM issues...try removing it and putting it back properly...also do the same with HDD once

Comment: What brand laptop, and what brand BIOS?

Comment: i dont think i have a problem with my ram. as ive said in my post. i dont get these beeps with my previous operating system
my laptop is
eM350. i think my bios is insyde .. i cant remember >_< it flashes very fast during startup

Comment: @JonLloyd, please add the output of `sudo lshw | head -30` to our question. It has information regarding your laptop make and its BIOS.

Comment: description: Notebook
    product: eM350 (NetTopSku)
    vendor: eMachines
    version: V1.06
    serial: LUNAH0C058036099AB1601
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Intel_Mobile sku=NetTopSku uuid=9CE64E36-829C-B19C-2111-88AE1D8847B6

Comment: *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: eM350
       vendor: Acer
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.06
       serial: Base Board Serial Number
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Acer
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.06
          date: 07/08/2010
          size: 1MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb

Comment: *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 15
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 1GiB

Comment: what happens if you boot from a live CD?

Comment: For grub: This could be caused by a stuck key on the keyboard. https://askubuntu.com/questions/165929/how-do-i-get-gnu-grub-to-stop-beeping-and-allow-me-to-select-an-option-from-the

Answer (score 3):

The specific number and length of the beeps is a code telling you that a hardware problem has been detected.  I last encountered them with a graphics card that wasn't getting the correct power. Checking your computer's manual should list the specific codes, or you can check pages like this online:

http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Comment: yes i've tried that. but i don't get exact number of beeps all the time.. sometimes i get 15 seconds.. sometimes it take up to 1 minute. and then it stops. then my laptop continues to boot.

Comment: can you update your question to say whether it happens before or after the purple GRUB menu appears (I'm assuming before)?

Comment: yes it's before. and i dont have that purple grub menu.. after i installed 12.04 the grub menu doesn't show up anymore

Answer (score 2):

Beeping immediately after pressing the start button often means that your PC hardware is talking to you. You should have a look into your laptop's manual.

Comment: i get beeps after post. not after pressing the power button

Answer (score 1):

This is hardware related. Go to the manufactures homepage and look for help there.

This is not a problem with ram, because if it were ram then the system would not boot. I know, because I have encountered this myself.

Answer (score 1):

Temporarily we can avoid this beep sound while starting of the system by clicking "ctrl+shift+Fn" button for 3 to 4 times which is next to ctrl button as i have shown in the picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pajK9.png)

it works!!

Answer (score 0):

So BIOS completes, so at least the laptop thinks it's hardware is OK. But this beeping comes before the starting of software (the disk part of the boot)? I'd try the Live CD and see what happens there, that would tell you if it was software or hardware.

It could be audio driver issue.

Is it beeping regularly or could it be like holding down the keyboard too long? The Character Control-G would ring a terminal's bell if it was sent from somewhere. Bad keyboard perhaps?